# max-height:100% doesn't work on firefox and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, css

I wanna fit and expand image to browser's max height with css but max-height:100% doesn't work on firefox and IE. Both are latest version.  On FF and IE, the images are shown in original size. So it's too big. 
max-height:100% is valid only for chrome?
or Are there any solutions about this?

it's not for background image so that background-size:cover is not what I want to know.

PS: I dont need the images fit to browser's width. Only Max-HEIGHT:100%.

Comment: height:100%; as long as you have no inheriting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
#background{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
top:0px //Adjust this value
margin-left:0px; //Adjust this value
}
```

Comment: Oh, position:absolute works but I always want to put the images in the center of browser as well. If I use position:absolute;, #img {margin: 0 auto; } doesn't work.
how can I solve this ?

Comment: create a div align it in center put the image inside the div and give it margin-left to position it in center

Comment: how can I put the div in the middle of browsers without setting width:xx px? If I set the width of the div, The image inside the div cannot be put in the center because it is always in the left side of the div.
Does width:100% work to the outer div?